# SSIS 2017 "Execute SQL Task" fails Could not find stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ado.net, execute-sql-task

I'am using SSIS with an **ADO.NET** connection to Azure. Within SSIS I want to execute a procedure with one input and 2 output parameters. The input parameter is a static value. The Procedure works with T-SQL within SSMS.

I setup the "Execute SQL Task" as followed

**General**

- SQLStatement: `METRICE_VAULT.GP_1001_GENERIC_PRE_PROCESS 2, @INSTANCE, @PROCESS_STATUS`
- IsQueryStoredProcedure: True
- ConnectionType: ADO.NET
- ResultSet: None
- SQLSourceType: Direct input

**Parameter Mapping**
[image]

[image]

When I execute the "Execute SQL Task" I received the following error

> > Must declare the scalar variable "@". Possible failure reason: Problem with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly..

**Update**

After adding parameters name i am receiving the following error:

> Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "METRICE_VAULT.GP_1001_GENERIC_PRE_PROCESS 2,  @INS..." failed with the following error: "Could not find stored procedure 'METRICE_VAULT.GP_1001_GENERIC_PRE_PROCESS 2,  @INSTANCE  ,@PROCESS_STATUS'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the way to configure your parameters and properties. Set IsQueryStoredProcedure property to True and instead of writing exec ProcName you just have to give ProcName in sqlstatment if you are using ADO.NET Connection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I adjust the question. I now get another error message!

Comment: @Erikhoeven Did you modified the IsQueryStoredProcedure property to True ?

Comment: Yes i did change it to true

Comment: @Erikhoeven Can you confirm if you are using only the procedure name in SQLStatement instead of EXEC ProcedureName ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ADO.NET You must specify the parameter name. As example:

```
METRICE_VAULT.GP_1001_GENERIC_PRE_PROCESS 2,@param1, @param2
```

And don't use parameter index in parameter mapping tab as shown in the screenshot.

**Additional Information**

*You can refer to the following official documentation for more details and examples:*

- [Map Query Parameters to Variables in an Execute SQL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/map-query-parameters-to-variables-in-an-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014)

### Update 1

Try using a fully qualified name:

```
<database name>.<schema name>.<stored procedure name>
```

Or add a `USE <database>` command before the stored procedure execution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I adjust the question. I now get another error message!

Comment: @Erikhoeven Try using a fully qualified name: `<database name>.<schema name>.<stored procedure name>` or add a `USE <database>` command before the stored procedure execution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the direction of your parameters to INPUT.

Comment: The OP mentioned that `I want to execute a procedure with one input and 2 output parameters`

Comment: If you have OUTPUT parameters then result set should not be NONE.

Comment: That's not true, OUTPUT parameters is not related to ResultSet. **(ResultSet and parameters are not related at all!)**